# Minimum along a dimension in a Multi Dimensional arrays C++

Tags: c++, opencv, pointers, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have a 3D matrix of size (100,100,50).

```
 int sizes[]={100,100,50};
 Mat data_3d(3,sizes, CV_32FC1, cv::Scalar(0));
```

I want to find minimum  at every point along 3rd dimension to yield a 2D matrix.

OpenCv supports min,max finding only for 2D matrix. Please help me know if there are ready functions for min,max for nth dimension.

Comment: openCV is highly optimized for 2D matrices (images).

Comment: If you can have a `vector<Mat>`, each `Mat` being a 2d matrix, then it'll be far easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can slice the the 3D mat along the `z` dimension, and use `cv::min` to compare the slices.

Code:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main() 
{
    int sizes[] = {10, 7, 5};
    Mat data(3, sizes, CV_32F);

    // Init data with each plane a constant increasing value
    for (int z = 0; z < data.size[2]; ++z)
    {
        Range ranges[] = { Range::all(), Range::all(), Range(z, z + 1) };
        data(ranges) = data.size[2] - z;
    }


    // Compute minimum along 3rd dimension
    Mat minmat(data.size[0], data.size[1], data.type(), Scalar(DBL_MAX));

    for (int z = 0; z < data.size[2]; ++z)
    {
        Range ranges[] = { Range::all(), Range::all(), Range(z, z+1) };
        Mat slice(data(ranges).clone()); // with clone slice is continuous, but still 3d
        Mat slice2d(2, &data.size[0], data.type(), slice.data);

        cv::min(slice2d, minmat, minmat);
    }

    // minmat is a 10x7 mat containing in (y,x) the minimum value along z

    return 0;
}
```

Since OpenCV is better suited for 2d matrices, you should consider using a `vector<Mat>` instead (where each Mat in the vector is 2d).

This is the same code as above, using `vector<Mat>`:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    int size_h = 10;
    int size_w = 7;
    int size_z = 5;

    vector<Mat> data(size_z);   
    // Init data with each plane a constant increasing value
    for (int z = 0; z < size_z; ++z)
    {
        data[z] = Mat(size_h, size_w, CV_32F, Scalar(size_z - z));
    }

    // Compute minimum along 3rd dimension
    Mat minmat(size_h, size_w, CV_32F, Scalar(DBL_MAX));

    for (int z = 0; z < size_z; ++z)
    {
        cv::min(data[z], minmat, minmat);
    }

    // minmat is a 10x7 mat containing in (y,x) the minimum value along z

    return 0;
}
```

To access each matrix you do: `data[index]`, and to access the a pixel at a given row and col, you do: `data[index].at<float>(row, col)`;

Comment: Thanks Miki for the code.

I got to know how to use range datatype... its pretty helpful.

I will try using vector<Mat> also as the Opencv is more optimised in that sense.

Comment: @user2527599  If you need an example with vector<Mat> let me know

Comment: for vector<mat> images(10)....  we can access each image by using images.at(i)  but how do go i inside each element in a vector....

I mean how to access a pixel in a matrix for this vector.... it seems like images.at(1)[10,10] ..is not working.. any clue for pixel access in vector<mat> ?

Comment: yeah..pls provide that vector<mat> example