# How to access depth of a 3d matrix in opencv as a 1D array/vector

Tags: c++, opencv

```
int sizes[3] = {49, 49, 5};
cv::Mat matX(3, sizes, CV_32F);
```

How to get a pixel in all the 2d slices(2D matrices) in matX which has the same row, col index. Similar to `matX(row,col,:)` in MATLAB.

I've tried using this in a loop

```
cv::Range ranges[3];
ranges[0] = Range(r, r + 1); // Row
ranges[1] = Range(c, c + 1); // Column
ranges[2] = Range::all();    // Depth I suppose

cv::Mat depth = matX(ranges);
```

But depth comes out as a 3d matrix. Also, is there any way to view 3d matrices or have to loop and print?

Edit: This is what I used to get the depth. Not sure if it's the best way.

```
cv::Range ranges[3];
ranges[0] = Range(r, r + 1); // Row
ranges[1] = Range(c, c + 1); // Column
ranges[2] = Range::all();    // Depth I suppose

cv::Mat depth(matX(ranges).clone()); // This has the data I need but it's still 3d.
cv::Mat depth1D(1, &matX.size[2], depth.type(), depth.data);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minimum along a dimension in a Multi Dimensional arrays C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32584960/minimum-along-a-dimension-in-a-multi-dimensional-arrays-c)

Comment: Miki, the links show getting a 2D matrix right. I'm looking at getting the first/second pixel of all the images in the stack. I got a hint that I need to convert the result to 2D though. Thanks

Comment: Also related [How to modify part of the multi-dimensional matrix in openCV?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32733223/5008845)

Comment: I mixed up links :D. If these links don't help, please be more clear and we can come up with a solution

Comment: Miki, the links sure helped. I'll just edit so someone could use it.